# which wine command does not work(Ubuntu 20.04.LTS)

Tags: wine

I am trying to install a program with wine. It seems to be well installed, but the commands do not work.

First, I did the `winecfg` command, which had output

> Error: wine loader not found

Hence, I thought that wine was incompletely installed. I found that wine was in `/usr/bin`, which is inside the system path `$PATH`. However, the `which wine` command outputs nothing.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: PS. I uninstalled and reinstalled wine plenty times, but there was no difference